# Postgres to_tsvector is case sensitive on mac os

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, mac-os-x

On PostgreSQL 10.4 on Ubuntu 10.4-2.pgdg16.04+1

```
select to_tsvector('simple', 'БОЛЬШИЕ БУКВЫ');
```

returns `'большие':1 'буквы':2`

But on postgres 10.3 (installed by brew) on Mac Os High Sierra version 10.13.3 it returns `'БОЛЬШИЕ':1 'БУКВЫ':2` for not english letters

How can I fix it on Mac os?

Comment: For people who are not literate enough to understand Cyrillic letters, you're questions seems strange. You are inputting capital Cyrillic letters (or so it seems) and are receiving a lower-case result set. But on Mac OS you are receiving an exact match of what you "selected". Why should the result set on the **PostgreSQL/Ubuntu** combination be better than the **PostgreSQL\MacOS** combination? Could you explain a bit?

Comment: The same function has to give the same result regardless of OS. Now results are different and I want to understand why. For english letters both versions give lowercased result, but for russian - only ubuntu make it lowercased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ability to identify the case of characters depend on the `LC_CTYPE` of your database, which by default, depends on the environment in which the PostgreSQL instance has been created (with `initdb`).

For instance, on Ubuntu with PostgreSQL11:

```
tstc=# show lc_ctype;
 lc_ctype 
----------
 C

tstc=# select to_tsvector('simple', 'БОЛЬШИЕ БУКВЫ');
      to_tsvector      
-----------------------
 'БОЛЬШИЕ':1 'БУКВЫ':2
(1 row)
```

That's the result you got on your db on MacOS.

But when I'm logged to a different database, with an UTF-8 locale this time:

```
postgres=# show lc_ctype;
  lc_ctype   
-------------
 fr_FR.UTF-8
(1 row)

postgres=# select to_tsvector('simple', 'БОЛЬШИЕ БУКВЫ');
      to_tsvector      
-----------------------
 'большие':1 'буквы':2
(1 row)
```

Now letters are put in lower case.

The fix is to create the database with the correct `LC_CTYPE`. It cannot be changed afterwards. By default, this setting comes from `template1`, but it can be overriden by choosing `template0`, if `template1` does not suit you, for instance:

```
CREATE DATABASE newDB lc_ctype='C.UTF-8' template template0;
```

The locale specified with `lc_ctype` must also be supported by the system. Check with `locale -a` or some equivalent if that doesn't work on MacOS.